# How to fix "Parse error at METHODS: usage might be invalid MATLAB syntax.?

Tags: matlab, parse-error, matlab-app-designer

I am designer an application using MATLAB App Designer. The very first panel is the home page panel which has a drop-down to allow the user to choose which age category and proceed to the set of questions that fits their age. So, I have created another 3 panels to link with the age category.
The code for callback between drop down and others panels is shown below:

% Value changed function: DropDown

```
function DropDownValueChanged(app, event)

    value = app.DropDown.Value;

    % Hide all the panels
    app.PanelA.Visible = 'off';
    app.PanelB.Visible = 'off';
    app.PanelC.Visible = 'off';

    %If Panel 1 is selected, show panel 1
    if strcmp(value,'Panel A')
        app.PanelA.Visible = 'on';
    elseif strcmp(value,'Panel B')
        app.PanelB.Visible = 'on';
    elseif strcmp(value,'Panel C')
        app.PanelC.Visible = 'on';
    end
end
```

However, problem occurred when I was trying to simulate the application. 
I got this error message:
Error using DRS
Error: File: DRS.mlapp Line: 94 Column: 5
Illegal use of reserved keyword "methods".

And when I put cursor on methods and it shows:
"Parse error at METHODS: usage might be invalid MATLAB syntax"

The following is the code that went wrong, the very first line got an error as mentioned before.

```
    methods (Access = private)
    % App initialization and construction
    methods (Access = private)

    % Create UIFigure and components
    function createComponents(app)
```

What should I do to rectify the problem? 
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Could you at least show the code where you use `methods`? I don’t see it in the code you posted. Please read [mre].

Comment: Thank you Cris for responding to my question. I actually solved the issue by just adding an "end" to the function and the issue was no longer ocurred. I am not sure whether it was the correct way of doing it but however it helped me to get the issue done.and I shall remove the question now.